# how to get a image for a label from FileOutPutStream in java?

Tags: java, jlabel, qr-code

i created a QR generator in java.I tested my application using FileOutPutStream.So it worked properly,now i need to get the generated QR image to a jLabel before save,so how to do this.please help me??

this is my code:

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = QRCode.from("Hello World").to(ImageType.PNG).stream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream webout = QRCode.from("http://viralpatel.net").to(ImageType.PNG).stream();

        try {
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\QR_Code.JPG"));
            BufferedImage image= ImageIO.read(new FileOutputStream(fout)));
            fout.write(out.toByteArray());

            fout.flush();
            fout.close();

        } catch (Exception e){

        }
```

Comment: what are you feeding the output stream, because if it is bytes then all you need to do is replace FileOutputStream with FileInputstream

Comment: if u create a buffer image before save it then u can use  buffered  image to show in label

Answer (score 1):

- A ByteArrayOutputStream is used to write to a final byte array.
- A ByteArrayInputStream allows to read from an initial byte array.

So:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = ...
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
BufferedImage image= ImageIO.read(in);
```